# determining when a body attached to a rope has moved a specific distance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, game-physics, box2d-iphone

Using Cocos2d and Box2d I have made a rope of revolute joint segments with a body attached to the lowest segment (weldJoint) which I move using a mouse joint. The rope is hanging downward. How can I set conditions to tell when the attached body has covered double the distance it is swiped (mouseJoint) in the opposite direction. For example, if I swipe the body (attached to the rope) 45 degrees to the left I should know (maybe by some message or something) when it swings back 45 degrees to the right. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying, but have you tried adding a sensor (Section 6.3 of [Box2dManual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html)) when you release it? If your physics are pretty simple, you should be able to get away with adding it at the same Y as the release point and making it's X flipped about the joint location.